# Synchronize two threads

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization

There are two threads `data_collect_thread` and `data_process_thread`.

`data_collect_thread` collects the data and pushes the data into a queue which is 4 times faster than the `data_process_thread` which dequeue data from the queue and processing it.

In this condition, the heap gets overflowed after some time due to slower dequeue compared to pushing data to the queue.

I cannot wait in `data_collect_thread` until the `data_process_thread` processing the data. I need to get real-time data without any missing.

Please suggest an algorithm to avoid this issue?

More details:

The queue is a doubly-linked list, so I need to allocate memory in heap and push this to queue. After dequeue, the memory is freed.

Comment: Uh, start more of `data_collect_thread` so they can keep up? I don't think there can be an algorithmic fix for this. Obviously the queue and the code must be thread-safe, and so on.

Comment: check if `data_collect_thread` can have multiple instances, to process the input.

Comment: You could run 4 instances of the `data_process_thread` and then rotate them. Only works, if you would have 5 cores. Is one collecting time really the frequence you need to collect the real-time data or can you lower the period?

Comment: You should add more details to your question about the data collection and processing. (What exactly do you have to do?) Will the data collection thread permanently send data or do you get bursts of data followed by some time interval without new data? How is the queue implemented?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX yes, 1 collecting time = frequency need to collect the real-time data from the i2c sensor, sorry I cannot run 4 instances, it's a single core. It makes slower the system. Thank you.

Comment: Could you possibly just write the data to file and process later? How long would you be collecting data?

Comment: If you are on a single core, having two threads won't give you any benefit. In contrast, you have context switches, and these *cost* performance. Have you tested if you remain fast enough having just one single thread? Single core – i. e. a micro-controller? Maybe you should just select a faster one?

Comment: @Aconcagua  Yes, I have tested with a single thread, I missed a lot of data from sensor due to large processing time of single data, I have avoided this missing with context switching(multiple threads). Data is produced at a rate of 400Hz, so I need to read data within 2.5ms. Thank you.

Comment: There is no way something slower to be quicker  than something faster. RT system has drop same data.

Comment: Buy a computer that is four times faster

Comment: It looks pretty much as if your CPU simply is too slow to do both tasks at once. Just adding a second thread won't make the CPU itself faster, in contrast, if you don't have a separate core the thread can run on, you'll only get even slower. So you'll have to rethink over the entire design. Either you live with that you cannot process all data at the desired rate, so you'll read at some lower one – or you get faster hardware (or additional one). If you don't read non-stop, you might write the data to some larger external memory and fetch back when reading from sensor is done.

Comment: " it's a single core" hmm... then it probably makes no sense at all to apply threading

Comment: Why only a single core?

Comment: *"Please suggest an algorithm to avoid this issue? "* - Impossible, since we don't even know what the algorithm should do.

Comment: @klutt  I am trying to solve this using ping pong buffers.

Comment: Thank you for all, I will choose a faster controller or one with multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad to give a specific answer, but imho interesting enough anyway. So I'll give some solutions.

- Buy a computer that is four times faster.
- Create more instances of `data_process_thread`. May work if you have several cores.
- Optimize the algorithm and/or code for `data_process_thread`.
- Rewrite `data_process_thread` completely to run on a gpu.
- Create a cluster of computers with a load balancer.
- Spool the queue to disk. May work if you get some pauses in the data flow.

I might add that if you add enough constraints on your problem, it might turn out unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a water-tank into which you are continuously pumping water. You are also taking water out of the tank through a small pipe. Unless you remove water at a faster rate than you pump it in, the tank will **always** overflow, sooner or later. Same is true in data processing. You have to consume data at a rate equal to or faster than the rate at which you produce it or else you will, sooner or later, run out of memory. It is a fact of life.

In case the data comes in bursts, with some periods of down time, then you can get away with slower processing by using a large-enough buffer to hold the data for a while. But in your case, it looks like you are streaming or sampling continuously at a fixed rate.

Since you say you have no control over the speed at which data arrives, the only other option you have is to optimize `data_process_thread()` so that it runs faster than the speed at which data arrives. 2.5ms seems like good enough time to do a decent amount of processing. Take a long and hard look at your processing code and profile it to understand where it spends CPU time. Then try to optimize it to make it run faster.

PS: I just saw in your comments that you are reading from I2C. Assuming you are or some kind of embedded microcontroller, try to use DMA to copy data to memory from the I2C peripheral if your microcontroller supports it. Reducing the number of interrupts will probably free you more CPU time for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- Process all of the data.
- Don't process all of the data.

If you want to process all of the data, then you need to process it as fast as it comes in. So you either need a faster computer, or more computers, or a faster processing algorithm. Full stop. Those are the only things you can do.

If you don't want to process all of the data, you could make it so the collection thread deletes the data (instead of putting it in the queue) if there is too much data already in the queue.

These are your options. Choose one.

Comment: Yes, I need to process all of its data. So I need a faster computer. I cannot optimize my current algorithm, time-consuming in processing task is a radio transmit.

Comment: @TiYan if this is a microcontroller (a guess since it's an i2c sensor) you're in luck. If you had a desktop computer and needed one 4 times faster, you might have a problem finding one. But it's probably easy to find another microcontroller 4 times faster than your microcontroller.

Comment: Yes, It is a microcontroller. Thank you for the great support.

Comment: 'a radio transmit'???  That is an I/O operation that does not require CPU.  If you buy a 1024-core super computer, it will not help at all:((